# Android TV settings menu in Leanback

Tags: android, youtube, television, leanback

I'm currently developing an Android TV application. I'm trying to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px1rB.png) (catalog on the left side and navigation to the right side). I've tried to do it with 2 fragments, views,  but I've had navigation and focusing issues. Is it possible to get this with BrowseFragment? Are there any other effective ways?